# IMAP - editing a draft or existing message?

Tags: imap

For those of you familiar with IMAP - If I retrieve a draft message (or any message for that matter), and I wish to update it / edit it, what commands should I use?

The only command i've come across is `Append`, which appears to only insert, meaning I would have to delete the previous draft from the mailbox?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

IMAP is designed for server-side management of mailboxes, not for editing messages.  So yes, you would have to retrieve the contents of the desired message (`FETCH`), then delete that message from the server (`STORE` a `\Deleted` flag on the message and then `EXPUNGE` deleted messages), and then upload the updated message to the server (`APPEND`).  There are no IMAP commands for editing the contents of an existing message, only for updating flags related to existing messages (`STORE`).

Comment: Indeed, the specification guarantees that a specific message object (identified with a UID) is immutable.  That's an important guarantee for caching email clients.  Being able to edit a message would break that guarantee.

Comment: I just want to add that by RFC3501 UIDs are immutable only within session http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501#page-8

Comment: It can be desirable to edit an IMAP message.  With the proliferation of the ZenDesk email support system, thread/convo view in gmail + all clients break easily.  Gmail appears to use a combo of subject, to, from, and date range.  I prefer using the in reply-to-ID and message-ID's. Altering subjects to get the thread/convo view back would be great. Also adding my original email to the thread/convo instead of searching a support ID#.  Anyone aware of an IMAP client that does simple editing of subjects + removal of attachments where the email is marked where the files were saved to?

Comment: Note that the answer's reference to `DELETE` is not exactly accurate. IMAP's `DELETE` is for folders (or "mailboxes", as the spec calls them). Deleting messages is done via a combination of `STORE` and `EXPUNGE`.

Answer (score 6):

Remy's answer is correct. On top of that, you could optimize the process a bit if the server supports the `CATENATE` extension via `APPEND CATENATE` (so that you could save yourself uploading the existing attachments, etc).