# How to modify IMAP email headers (with imaplib in python)

Tags: python, exchange-server, imap

I'm successfully reading all email from an IMAP mailbox (Exchange on Outlook 365 with imaplib in python).

Now I want to make changes to the emails.

Specifically:

- How to change the categories on a email (stored in the Header as "Keywords: Category A, Category B")
- How to add/remove the "X-Message-Flag: Follow up"

**How can I modify the messages found in the IMAP mailbox?**

- Would creating a copy help me change the email? [IMAP - editing a draft or existing message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16945041/imap-editing-a-draft-or-existing-message)
- I found the STORE method but it seems to be focused on FLAGS such as \Seen or \Deleted

Comment: For headers, you need to download, modify, and `APPEND` the changed version, delete the old one.

Comment: How is it possible that from Outlook (web/desktop) I can change the header of the existing message (the UID of the edited messages on the IMAP session stays the same). Is Outlook talking to Exchange outside what's possible with IMAP?

Comment: Probably. It's also against imap spec: the text of imap messages are immutable; otherwise they cannot be cached by clients.

Comment: Outlook for windows talks using a proprietary exchange protocol.